# How does multiplying by trigonometric functions in a matrix transform the matrix?

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, transformation

I found this comic:

[image: XKCD comic showing a 90°-rotation matrix applied to a column vector equals that column vector drawn sideways]

But I can't understand the humor because I can't understand how trig functions affect matrix multiplication. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 8):

The matrix $$\left[\begin{align} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{align} \right]$$
when it acts on a vector it rotates the vector by $\theta$ in clockwise direction. Hence when $\theta = 90^{\circ}$, it rotates the vector $$\left[\begin{align} a_1 \\ a_2 \end{align} \right]$$ from vertical to horizontal clockwise.

Comment: $\theta=-90$...

Comment: @lhf: Thats why I have written clockwise direction.

Comment: Oops, missed that *clockwise*.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the rotation matrix they write there is

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\ 
-1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array} \right)
$$

If you multiply a vector $\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a_{1} \\ 
a_{2} \\ 
\end{array} \right)$ by this matrix then you end up with $\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a_{2} \\ 
-a_{1} \\ 
\end{array} \right)$ If you draw a picture in the $xy$ plane connecting each of $(a_{1},a_{2})$ and $(a_{2},-a_{1})$ with the origin, it will be clear that the latter is a 90 degree rotation of the former.

Answer (score 4):

Because...

[image]

Sorry couldn't resist when it was bumped.

Answer (score 3):

That's a $-90$-degree rotation matrix.

Comment: Wow! A highly improbable case of two events occurring simultaneously! Your answer and mine show the same "answered 2 secs ago"!