# does multiplying a trigonometric functions in 2×2 matrix by a 2×1 matrix output a 1×2 matrix or a 2×1 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry

the figure comes from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/43073/684611)

[image]

if I consider this vector

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a_{1} \\ 
a_{2} \\ 
\end{array} \right)$$

as a 2 by 1 matrix

is the result on the right of the equation a 2 by 1 matrix which looks like

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a_{2} \\ 
-a_{1} \\ 
\end{array} \right)$$

or a 1 by 2 matrix which looks like

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a_{2}& -a_{1}
\end{array} \right)$$

Comment: The joke in the comic is that the rotation matrix changes the coordinates so that the **coordinate change corresponds to a rotation**, not visually rotating the mathematical notation of the coordinates (vector).

Comment: What's a trigonometric function of a matrix???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying a $\color{red}2\times \color{blue}2$ matrix ($\color{red}2$ rows and $\color{blue}2$ columns) by a $\color{blue}2\times1$ matrix ($\color{blue}2$ rows and $1$ column) makes sense because the blue $\color{blue}2$'s are equal, and the result is a $\color{red}2\times 1$ matrix ($\color{red}2$ rows and $1$ column).

The mnemonic that I learned back in the day for working out the dimensions of matrices in a product looks like this:
$$
"(\color{red}2\times \color{blue}2)\cdot (\color{blue}2\times1) = \color{red}2\times 1"
$$
where the inner $\color{blue}2$'s are equal (otherwise the product doesn't make sense), and cancel out, while the outer $\color{red}2$ and $1$ stay where they are.

Answer (score 1):

The result is $\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a_{2} \\ 
-a_{1} \\ 
\end{array} \right).$